# copy Excel data into text file

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have done the below code to copy Excel cell data to a txt file. I have to create one text file each for each cell in an Excel. like if I have n cells data in Excel I need n txt files.

```
Sub ExportToNotepad()
  Dim wsData As Variant
  Dim myFileName As String
  Dim FN As Integer
  Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim myString As String
  Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sc00359878\Desktop\sample_excel.xlsx")

  lastrow = wb.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  sPath = "C:\Users\sc00359878\Desktop\output\"

  For p = 1 To lastrow
    wsData = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & p).Value

    If wsData = "" Then Exit Sub
    myFileName = "sMove.txt"
    myFileName = sPath & myFileName

    FN = FreeFile
    Open myFileName For Output As #FN
    Print #FN, wsData
    Close #FN

    myString = ""
  Next p
End Sub
```

I'm getting the below error when I tried running it.

[image]

Comment: Please clean up your code to make it more readable.  Add proper indentation and spacing.

Comment: I've rolled back your changes.  You can't make substantive changes to your question after someone has provided an answer that make the answer no longer applicable.  If you have a *different* question after someone has pointed out what your initial problem is, then post a *new* question.

Comment: thanks for making me to understand how stackoverflow works :) thumbs up

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other "flavors" of VB, you can't declare variables as data types in VBScript because [VBScript is not a strongly-typed language](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198856.aspx).  In other words,

```
Dim wsData As Variant
```

should be

```
Dim wsData
```

and you'll need to fix all the other variable declarations that do that.

Comment: Thank you, i have changed all the variable declarations and now im getting new error in line 27 and char 17 , expected end of statements @roryap

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx) for information about file I/O in VBScript.

Comment: At any rate, I answered your question.  Converting your code from VBA to VBScript is off-topic for stack overflow.  If you agree that I answered the question you originally asked, then you should mark this answer.  There may be other resources online to help you convert code between languages.

Comment: @SharathChandra I posted some guidelines for [translating VBA to VBScript](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) in my blog a while ago.

Comment: Thank you :) @AnsgarWiechers